# Python list copy and slice modifying original list

Tags: python, list, mutable, in-place

I have a list as shown below:

```
voting_records = [['1.', 'DIRECTOR', 'Management'],
 ['1', 'Allison Grant Williams', 'For'],
 ['2', 'Sheila Hartnett-Devlin', 'For'],
 ['3', 'James Jessee', 'For'],
 ['4', 'Teresa Polley', 'For'],
 ['5', 'Ashley T. Rabun', 'For'],
 ['6', 'James E. Ross', 'For'],
 ['7', 'Rory Tobin', 'For']]
```

I created a copy of this list named `voting_records_short` using list comprehension:

```
cnames = ["Record","Proposal","Sponsor","VoteCast"]
voting_records_short = [record for record in voting_records if len(record) < len(cnames)]
```

Then I created a slice of `voting_records_short` and save it in `directors`. I then modify the `directors` list in  a for loop as shown below:

```
if len(voting_records_short) == 0: pass
else:
    ifdirector = ["DIRECTOR" in record for record in voting_records_short]
    if True in ifdirector:
        directorindx = int(ifdirector.index(True))
        directorline = [voting_records_short[directorindx]]
        directors = voting_records_short[directorindx+1:]
        sponsoridx = cnames.index("Sponsor")
        for ls in range(len(directors)):
            directors[ls][0] = directorline[0][0] + directors[ls][0]
            directors[ls][1] = directorline[0][1] + " " +directors[ls][1]
            directors[ls].insert(sponsoridx,directorline[0][-1])
```

Why does modifying directors list in the for loop modifies both the `voting_records_short` list and `voting_records` as shown in the outputs below:

```
In [2]: voting_records
Out[2]: 
[['1.', 'DIRECTOR', 'Management'],
 ['1.1', 'DIRECTOR Allison Grant Williams', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.2', 'DIRECTOR Sheila Hartnett-Devlin', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.3', 'DIRECTOR James Jessee', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.4', 'DIRECTOR Teresa Polley', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.5', 'DIRECTOR Ashley T. Rabun', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.6', 'DIRECTOR James E. Ross', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.7', 'DIRECTOR Rory Tobin', 'Management', 'For']]

In [9]: voting_records_short
Out[9]: 
[['1.', 'DIRECTOR', 'Management'],
 ['1.1', 'DIRECTOR Allison Grant Williams', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.2', 'DIRECTOR Sheila Hartnett-Devlin', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.3', 'DIRECTOR James Jessee', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.4', 'DIRECTOR Teresa Polley', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.5', 'DIRECTOR Ashley T. Rabun', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.6', 'DIRECTOR James E. Ross', 'Management', 'For'],
 ['1.7', 'DIRECTOR Rory Tobin', 'Management', 'For']]
```

I was expecting that only the `directors` list will be modified (and maybe `voting_records_short` but I'm not sure) but why is the original `voting_records` list modified? I'd appreciate any help?

Comment: because they all are referring to the same sublists. Nowhere did you ever copy any of the sublists.

Answer (score 1):

You were iterating over the original voting_records and storing references to each of those records in a new list; so, changes made to records with the references will modify both lists--as said above: deepcopy

```
from copy import deepcopy
copy_records = deepcopy(voting_records)
voting_records_short = [record for record in copy_records if len(record) < len(cnames)]
```

and after running your code:

```
[['1.', 'DIRECTOR', 'Management'], ['1', 'Allison Grant Williams', 'For'], ['2', 'Sheila Hartnett-Devlin', 'For'], ['3', 'James Jessee', 'For'], ['4', 'Teresa Polley', 'For'], ['5', 'Ashley T. Rabun', 'For'], ['6', 'James E. Ross', 'For'], ['7', 'Rory Tobin', 'For']]
[['1.', 'DIRECTOR', 'Management'], ['1.1', 'DIRECTOR Allison Grant Williams', 'Management', 'For'], ['1.2', 'DIRECTOR Sheila Hartnett-Devlin', 'Management', 'For'], ['1.3', 'DIRECTOR James Jessee', 'Management', 'For'], ['1.4', 'DIRECTOR Teresa Polley', 'Management', 'For'], ['1.5', 'DIRECTOR Ashley T. Rabun', 'Management', 'For'], ['1.6', 'DIRECTOR James E. Ross', 'Management', 'For'], ['1.7', 'DIRECTOR Rory Tobin', 'Management', 'For']]
```